# NSString's stringByAppendingPathComponent: removes a '/' in http://

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, nsstring

I've been modifying some code to work between Mac OS X and iPhone OS.

I came across some code that was using `NSURL`'s `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` (added in 10.6), which as some may know, isn't available in the iPhone SDK.

My solution to make this code work between OS's is to use

```
NSString *urlString = [myURL absoluteString];
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"helloworld"];
myURL = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
```

The problem with this is that `NSString`'s `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` seems to remove one of the /'s from the http:// part of the URL.

Is this intended behaviour or a bug?

---

### Edit

Ok, So I was a bit too quick in asking the question above. I re-read the documentation and it **does** say:

> Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs)

However, it doesn't give any pointers in the right direction for what to do if you need to append a path component to a URL on the iPhone...

I could always just do it manually, adding a /if necessary and the extra string, but I was looking to keep it as close to the original Mac OS X code as possible...

Comment: This does not however work on a file path with a service prefix.  For example, file:///Users/myuser/Documents will get mangled the same as your web URL example. Found this out the hard way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would implement a `myURLByAppendingPathComponent:` method on NSURL that does the same thing. The reason to give it a different name is so it doesn't override the Apple-provided method when Apple gets around to porting the 10.6 API to the iPhone (so the "my" is just an example — the point is that it's unlikely somebody else would write a method with that name).

It seems to me you just want to mess with the path rather than the whole URL. Here's an untested example:

```
- (NSURL *)myURLByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)component {
    NSString *newPath = [[self path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
    return [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme: [self scheme] 
                                     host: [self host] 
                                     path: newPath]
                                     autorelease];
}
```

It would only work correctly with URLs that have file-like paths, but I'm pretty sure the Apple method works the same way. At any rate, hopefully it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: I like this answer, but might suggest an improvement by making the new method a category of NSURL?

Comment: Be careful.  With this, I believe, you'll lose a custom port.  e.g., http://example.com:3003/ ==> http://example.com

Answer (score 13):

#### URLByAppendingPathComponent

Since iOS 4, `URLByAppendingPathComponent` is available on iOS and handles the two slashes correctly. (OS X had it since 10.6., as Chuck points out)

```
myURL = [myURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello world"]
// http://foo/bar/hello%20world
```

Note that unlike `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, this method escapes the argument.

#### URLWithString:relativeToURL:

Alternatively, there is `URLWithString:relativeToURL:`, which does not escape. So if the url component is already escaped, use:

```
myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"hello%20world" relativeToURL:myURL]
// http://foo/bar/hello%20world
```

Note that myURL needs to end with a slash here and the added segment must not have a leading slash.

Answer (score 5):

The [NSString Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) says this about `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`

> Note that this method only works with
>   file paths (not, for example, string
>   representations of URLs).

So, I think it's a case of "Don't Do That".

Use `-stringByAppendingString:` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the note in the documentation after posting the question. See my edit.

I could use `stringByAppendingString:` yes. Only thing preventing me doing that was that I didn't wan't to have to write the code to check whether or not I should also append a / or not before the string, which NSURL's `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` did for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple work around.
Using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", server, file] works fine.

E.g. server : ftp://www.server.com and file : file.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSString *)urlStringPathWithComponents:(NSArray *)paths
{
    NSString *url = @"";
    for( NSString *item in paths)
    {
        if([item isEqualToString:paths.firstObject])
        {
            url = [url stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item]];
        }else{
            url = [url stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", item]];
        }

    }
    return url;
}
```

As you see the code above is a class method and this permit use in anywhere without a instance of an object.

Note: Always the first object of the array must be a base url.